# Из тега select выбрать id товара и отдать php обработчику для добавление в CRM

Tags: php, form, select

Из тега select выбрать id товара и отдать php обработчику для добавление в CRM.

Выберите героя
    рубашка
    штаны
    шляпа

```
Вот кусок кода добавления в црмку:
//***************** Страница с завершением заказа ******************
session_start();

// формируем массив с товарами в заказе (если товар один - оставляйте только 
первый элемент массива)
products_list = array(
0 => array(
        'product_id' => $_REQUEST['product_id'],    //код товара (из 
каталога CRM)
        'price'      => $_REQUEST['product_price'], //цена товара 1
        'count'      => '1',                     //количество товара 1
```

Comment: <form action="select1.php" method="post">
 
    <option disabled>Выберите героя</option>
    <option value="id1">рубашка</option>
   <option value="id2">рубашка</option>
    <option value="id2">шляпа</option>
   </select></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
  </form>

Answer (score 1):

> PHP

```
// ...Вот кусок кода добавления в црмку:
//***************** Страница с завершением заказа ******************
session_start();

/* формируем массив с товарами в заказе (если товар один - оставляйте только 
первый элемент массива) */
if (!empty($_POST)) {
   products_list = array(
   0 => array(
      'product_id' => $_POST['product_id'], //код товара (из каталога CRM)
      'price'      => $_POST['product_price'], //цена товара 1
      'count'      => $_POST['product_count'], //количество товара 1...
```

> HTML

```
<form action="select1.php" method="post">
 <select name="product_id">
   <option disabled>Выберите героя</option>
   <option value="id1">рубашка</option>
   <option value="id2">рубашка 2</option>
   <option value="id3">шляпа</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```